# How do I use Ruby classes packaged using warbler as a jar in Java code?

Tags: java, jar, jruby, warbler

I've a ruby application which I compiled into a jar using warbler. I'm able to run it as a standalone using a command like `java -jar executable.jar`. But I'm unable to figure out how I'd use this jar in Java code. Specifically, I want to create objects of my Ruby classes in the Java code and then call the methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can start it with `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/java", "-jar", "executable.jar");
processBuilder.directory(new File("preferred/working/directory"));
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

or another way if you use Windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start executable.jar");
```

Comment: I specifically wanted to create objects of my Ruby classes in the java code. Technically, Java objects of my Ruby classes if I may say so. The Ruby classes use Ruby gems which I've packaged as a jar (executable.jar). I've edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: @arrac - maybe it is better for you to use https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/StandaloneJarsAndClasses - to generate Java classes from Ruby?